# Registro duplicado em mysql

Tags: mysql

estou com problemas ao criar uma tabela e inserir alguns registros para que eu trabalhe com algumas consultas.

Por mais que eu crie uma tabela teste apenas com ID e nome. Ao inserir pela ferramenta mesmo do mysql ele insere o mesmo registro 2 vezes!! Duplicado.

Já tentei em meu banco de dados na nuvem, localmente, em windows, em linux e ios.

As vezes quando limpo o cache ele vai apenas um registro, mas depois volta a duplicar ! O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Não há como saber sem você especificar o código que utilizou e a descrição da tabela no banco. Você pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar estes detalhes.

Comment: não usei codigo, eu fui direto pelas ferramentas do proprio mysql. Não está fora dos padrões que o professor ensinou, até mesmo os da web.

Comment: Poste a estrutura de sua tabela, e tente fazer o insert manualmente, sem ser pela interface.

Comment: vou tentar e já lhe retorno

Comment: Qual ferramenta você esta utilizando?

Comment: Galera, problema resolvido. Eu estava encabulado pois meu banco e tabelas estavam corretos! Fui testar com outro navegador(safari e mozilla) e funcionou como é esperado. Acontece que limpei o cache do Navegador Chrome e voltou a funcionar! Considerem essa dúvida solucionada. Obrigado pela atenção e ajuda.